# Read/Sort a large .CSV File

Tags: c++, csv, bucket

So conceptually I'm reading in a file with ~2 million lines of data.  I'm looking to sort, store and apply other functions to the data later.

1. I've been told this is referred to as "buckets" but I'm unclear whether this is something pre-defined or a user-defined data type.  So I'm curious whether a linked list or array or another combination would be advisable?
2. Do I need to worry about the size of the file? Will most compilers be able to handle that all going on concurrently or will I need to partition the data first (i.e. divide into each bucket, store in its own file, then use another code, etc)?
3. If #2 is required, does C++ have the functionality to save multiple files per execution? Meaning a) create bucket1 file.txt; b) populate bucket1 file; close bucket1 file; d) create bucket2 file; ...

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I gather from your post that you are writing this in C++.  However, the details are a bit sparse apart from the sorting requirement.  But what are you sorting on?  Are all fields interpreted as text?  Are some numbers?  Are there multiple keys?

If you don't absolutely need to write this in C++, and you are on Linux, just invoke /bin/sort to do the sorting.  This may seem like a cop-out, but commercial software like Talend even resorts to that.

But if you must write new code in C++, these are my recommendations:

1) Is the CSV file escaped?  In other words, do embedded quotes and delimiters need special treatment?  You have to figure this out first.

2) Check this out: http://mybyteofcode.blogspot.com/2010/02/parse-csv-file-with-boost-tokenizer-in.html

3) A simple representation of the scanned input is `vector<vector<string> >`.  But it is unwieldy.  Instead, wrap a class around `vector<string>` and make a vector of pointers to those classes, one per line of input, and sort those instead.

4) You should be able to sort ~2M "medium" rows in memory these days.  Just use std::sort.  But for full generality, you will need to consider, what if it doesn't fit into memory?  The most common answer to this is to sort chunks at a time, write the results to disk, and then merge it all using a priority-queue or similar structure.

Comment: Example of the file:
"1055,1055,1042,3006,3072,3031,3342,236"
I'm wanting to store the first 6 values in buckets defined by the 7th.  No discernible limit on the first 6, 7 slot seems to fall between 0 and 450.

Other than the commas and eol there are no special characters or delimiters.

Thank you for links and other pointer.